# SAPUI5 Custom control library theme

Tags: sapui5

I've recently created a SAPUI5 Library which contains a lot of custom controls to re-use, but I can't find a way to make applications which include the library, to load the `.less` theme files which are defining the custom controls styles.

So basically, what I would want to do is make the library embed custom control style to others applications.

Here is the `manifest.json` :

```
{
"_version": "1.7.0",

"sap.app": {
    "id": "zproject",
    "type": "library",
    "embeds": [],
    "i18n": "messagebundle.properties",
    "applicationVersion": {
        "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "title": "{{title}}",
    "description": "{{description}}",
    "ach": "",
    "resources": "resources.json",
    "offline": false
},
"sap.ui": {
    "technology": "UI5",
    "deviceTypes": {
        "desktop": true,
        "tablet": true,
        "phone": false
    },
    "supportedThemes": [
        "sap_hcb",
        "sap_belize",
        "sap_belize_plus"

    ]
},

"sap.ui5": {
    "dependencies": {
        "minUI5Version": "1.30.0",
        "libs": {
            "sap.ui.core": {
                "minUI5Version": "1.30.0"
            }
        }
    },
    "contentDensities": {
        "compact": true,
        "cozy": false
    }
},

"sap.platform.hcp": {
    "uri": ""
},

"sap.fiori": {
    "registrationIds": [],
    "archeType": "reusecomponent"
}
```

Here is my folder structure:

[image]

I can give you any more informations you could need, but I thought these are the most usefull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I still don't know why it isn't directly being loaded by the theme, but I found two ways to make it:

- The `sap.ui.dom.includeStylesheet()` method usable directly in components to load per component CSS [Documentation here](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/module%3Asap%2Fui%2Fdom%2FincludeStylesheet)
- Add a resource in the application including the library (once the library application is deployed, it builds the `.less` files to a `library.css` file) in the `manifest.json` file :

  ```
       "resources": {
       "css": [{
           "uri": "css/style.css"
       }, {
           "uri": "/resources/YOURLIBRARY/themes/base/library.css" 
       }]
   },
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and finally I found the answer in the api documentation of SAPUI5: [sap.ui.getCore().initLibrary](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.65.14/#/api/sap.ui.core.Core/methods/initLibrary)

In my case, the property `noLibraryCSS` was set to `true`, which means, that no theme is loaded. Please double check the `library.js` and set this property to `false` - or completely remove it, because the default value is `false`.